# Redis Cache Serialization wrt ResponseEntity or JSON format response

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, redis

Summary :
I've been facing this problem regards the Redis Cache Serialization with respect to ResponseEntity or JSON format response.

Issue Description :
I Build a Springboot application college-app contains department-service , student-service & faculty-service. In which I tried Redis cache implementation for department-service. So on the first hit to fetch department data http://localhost:8080/department-service/departments/1 - receives response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "IT",
            "comments": "test",
            "createdAt": "2024-01-10T10:38:53Z",
            "updatedAt": null
        }
    ],
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "total": null,
    "currentPageTotal": 0
}
```

but if I try the same again, its shows some exception ( attached ).

So If any expertise in this area would be immensely valuable to me, and I would greatly appreciate any assistance you could provide.

source code : [redis-cache-impl](https://github.com/VigneshbabuOfficial/college-app/tree/redis-cache-impl)

Exception :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1709809251660,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/department-service/departments/1"
}
```

[1_redis_cache_serialization_issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnnXM.png)